# Sorting multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array based on 1 field so when I run a `foreach` loop to loop through it will be sorted in the right order...

I have tried several sources but found very few results on multi-dimensional array sorting...

When I run the loop on the below array it shows `id` field order as `1|2` i want it to be `2|1` what would be the best way to achieve this?

Basically just sort it in descending order...

Array:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(4) {
            [0]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            [1]=> string(0) "" 
            ["invoicenum"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(4) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
            [1]=> string(0) "" 
            ["invoicenum"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve post that sorted array .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu No, I want to list it in a select box sorted...

Comment: How would the sorting work exactly? What kind of data structure can we expect? Is it always just one `[0]` index in the inner array? Or could there be more? How would it be sorted then?

Comment: @deceze yes. It would remain in this structure, 1 main array and only single level child arrays that follow.

Comment: Then all you need to do is http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476, with `$a[0][..]` in your comparison callback.

Comment: Thank you it worked :) @deceze

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $mid[$key]  = $row['id'];
}

// Use $data to sort by the common key
array_multisort($mid, SORT_DESC, $data);
?>
```